# How to write a simple testing case using XUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-core-1.0, xunit.net

Totally new to testing, I have a controller like this:

```
public class CheckRegController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public CheckRegController(ApplicationDbContext context, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _context = context;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(string var1, int numberusers)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now I have added a test project in which I am trying to use XUnit and Moq. I just wanted to create an object of controller like I have done in a very simple project, but it doesn't work in this.When I tried:

```
CheckRegController cr = new CheckRegController();
```

It says:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'context' of
>   'CheckRegController.CheckRegController(ApplicationDbContext,
>   IOptions)'   XUnitTestProjectOA

Then I tried:

```
var moqHome = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

but I don't know is it right or not OR what I need to do ahead?
How to pass `_context` and `_appsettings` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. Mock the dependencies and inject them into the subject under test.

```
//Arrange
var dbmock = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
//...setup dbmock as needed to exercise test
var options = new Mock<IOption<AppSetting>();
var appSetting = new AppSetting {
    //...populate appSetting as needed to exercise test
};
options.Setup(_ => _.Value).Returns(appSetting);

var sut = new CheckRegController(dbMock.Object, options.Object);
var var1 = "testing";
var numberusers = 2;

//Act
var actual = sut.Get(var1,numberusers)

//Assert
//...assert expected behavior to actual.
```

I would also suggest abstracting away the context to also make the controller more maintainable.

Comment: That's exactly what i want...but in case of UnitTestProject, we use [TestMethod] attribute and by clicking on test case we can run any test case but in XUnitTestCase, I have [Fact] attribute and I am unable to run the test case? How to  run it? I am using command:  dotnet test -method namespace.projectname.methodname? but it's not working.

Comment: It's giving me the error on dbmock.object that-
 Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException: 'Can not instantiate proxy of class: abc.Data.ApplicationDbContext.?

Comment: @Mogli That is why I had advised about abstracting the db context to allow for more flexibility.